# Get all running applications (chromium...gedit...etc) [C++ / Linux]

Tags: c++, linux, taskbar

I currently have an application that needs to know all the applications running on the system, not daemons, but apps like: Chromium, Firefox, gedit ... etc ... with Importance therefore quite high. Basically, you see your taskbar? I would like to display each open application that is listed there in my application.

I have no ideas, thanks for your help.

(Note : program with gtkmm-3.0 / C++ on Linux).

Comment: There are several ways to do this: http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/show-all-running-processes-in-linux/

Comment: This question might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/939778/linux-api-to-list-running-processes

Comment: My "taskbar" usually only displays only "applications" that have windows open. Is that what you want?

Comment: I found an even better dup: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1018052/how-do-i-obtain-and-synchronize-a-complete-list-of-all-x11-windows

Answer (score 0):

`wmctrl -l`

From `man wmctrl`:
List the windows being managed by the window manager. 
...