# X Window System Window Hierarchy exploration program

Tags: linux, x11, xlib, spy++

Is there a program to explore X window hierarchy? Anything like Spy++ of MS
(http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460727.aspx)

Comment: Why exactly do you ask?

Comment: `xwininfo -root -tree`

Answer (score 3):

You could write one. Use [XQueryTree](http://tronche.com/gui/x/xlib/window-information/XQueryTree.html) starting from the root window.

Also, study carefully [EWMH](http://standards.freedesktop.org/wm-spec/wm-spec-latest.html). It might have something relevant (e.g. `_NET_CLIENT_LIST`)

At last, code your own [window manager](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_window_manager), or adapt an existing one to fit your needs. A window manager has to know the list of top-level windows.

Remember that some X top-level windows might have been opened by some *remote* [X11](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_Window_System) client application running on a *different* machine (e.g. thru `ssh -X`)

Look also into [`xps`](http://sourceforge.net/projects/motif-pstree/) and [xwininfo](http://www.x.org/archive/X11R7.5/doc/man/man1/xwininfo.1.html); see [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1018052/841108).