# Using the vala programming language, can you detect when other applications are full screen or maximized, and suspend their own programs?

Tags: gtk, gnome, vala

Using the vala programming language, can you detect when other applications are full screen or maximized, and suspend their own programs?
Is there a similar Demo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is something that can only be done by asking the window manager/compositor, since that is the component that actually deals with this kind of thing. And depending on the session type, this will or will not work.

- In Wayland, it is impossible to query info/events about other windows for security reasons.
- In X, this might be possible using things like `xwininfo` (see for more info https://stackoverflow.com/a/1018185/2921914). You can either directly call it and parse the result, or see which parts of the X protocol it uses by looking at its [source code](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/xorg/app/xwininfo/-/blob/master/xwininfo.c).

Since you mentioned [gnome] as a tag, you *might* be able to do this by writing your own GNOME Shell extension, since this has direct access GNOME Shell's internals.